# Como preservar a coluna de datas exportando um objeto ts ou xts do R para o excel?

Tags: r, datetime, séries-temporais

Estou trabalhando com um arquivo ts com duas variáveis

```
compib <- cbind(pimsaf, fumosaf)

head(compib)
      pimsaf  fumosaf
[1,] 77.74133 131.5189
[2,] 80.18227 131.6221
[3,] 79.77395 111.2698
[4,] 79.48862 117.7251
[5,] 79.19464 110.1054
[6,] 79.41282 105.1417
```

Se tento diretamente no "write.xlsx" ele não considera as datas, se tento transformar em um dataframe ele me retorna datas distorcidas:

```
date   pimsaf  fumosaf
1 2002.000 77.74133 131.5189
2 2002.083 80.18227 131.6221
3 2002.167 79.77395 111.2698
4 2002.250 79.48862 117.7251
5 2002.333 79.19464 110.1054
6 2002.417 79.41282 105.1417
```

Existe alguma maneira mais fácil de exportar um ts diretamente pro excel?